# AngularJS filtering by multiple tables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem filtering table data. I have a variable **vm.dataOfTables** which has content for more than one table (therefore the ng-repeat). 
I will filter every table by itself - with my approach at the botton I have the issue, that the tables share the same model variable.

Therefore my question would be how to set a unique model variable for each table - the amount of tables is random.

Thanks a lot!

```
<div ng-repeat='tableData in vm.dataOfTables'>
    <table class="table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.searchEmployeesText"></th>
                ...
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>         
        <tr ng-repeat="scheduleResponseContent in tableData.scheduleResponseContents | filter:vm.searchEmployeesText">
    ...
```

Comment: where is the UI for entering the filter text? Could just use child scope created by the `ng-repeat` of the tables or create a directive with isolated scope that represents each table

Comment: the input **<th><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.searchEmployeesText"></th>** is for entering the filter text. whould there any example how to haldle this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: ooops  didn't even notice that. Try removing `vm` from model should localize to child scope. `table` directive however would be best approach